# Charts js - How to make gridlines dash and How to make the gridlines stop at each point

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

So as the title states I'm trying to make the vertical gridline dashed. I tried using borderDash: [20, 30] on the Xaxes gridline but that didn't work. Also I was wondering if its possible to make the gridlines stop at each of the point on the graph.

Heres my code

```
$.getJSON(rawDataURL, function (json) {
    var data = prepData(json);
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var lineData = { 
            labels: data[0].x,
            datasets: [{
               tension:0,
               bezierCurve: false,
               data: data[0].y
              }]
            };
    var option =  {
        legend: {
                display:false
            },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false 
                },
                ticks: {
                   display: false
                }
            }],
             xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: true,
                    borderDash: [20, 30],
                    tickMarkLength:1 
                }       
            }]
        }
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{type:'line',data:lineData,options:option});
})
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request accepted to the core on Aug 11, 2016, which should be released soon. 
( https://github.com/karthikiyengar/Chart.js/commit/db457fe2294a03ac864f6dd219713398bbaf9d63 )

This will utilize the `borderDash` param that is passed to gridLines itself.